# ngx bootstrap date range picker pop up position and width

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx bootstrap date range picker in my application and it works fine except in one place which is far right to the screen. when I click the button the dates pop up but they stack on top of each other (instead of normal inline). I gave width to it and the pop up went inline but out of the screen with scroll bars.

how can I position the popup a bit to the left so it doesn't go outside the screen?

Comment: There's an option `placement` which you can play with

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work..Not sure what placement is supposed to do? Is it possible to change left,top position values for the pop up?